# mutate conditional column based on rowwise string detection in all other character columns

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr

imagine I have a simple tibble:

```
tribble(~a,~b,~c,
        1, "def", "abc",
        2, "def", "def")
```

I want to mutate a new column "d" with values conditioned on whether a string exists in all other columns. In this case, I'm looking for the string "abc". The final output would look like:

```
tribble(~a,~b,~c,~d,
        1, "def", "abc", "present",
        2, "def", "def", "absent")
```

In reality my tibble has ~20 columns, of which maybe 10 are character, and the strings I'm looking for are more complex, like `"[Aa]|[Cc]"`. I'm sure there's a simple-ish way with pmap,case_when and str_detect but can't work it out at all!

Answer (score 0):

Using `rowSums` in base R :

```
cols <- sapply(df, is.character)
df$d <- ifelse(rowSums(sapply(df[cols], grepl, pattern = 'a')) > 0, 
               'present', 'absent')
```

With `dplyr`, we can use `rowwise` with `c_across` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(d = if(any(str_detect(c_across(where(is.character)), 'a'))) 
                'present' else 'absent')

#      a   b     c     d      
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>  
#1     1 def   abc   present
#2     2 def   def   absent
```

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry, I should have been clearer that the string just be partial, which is why I was thinking str_detect. So in the above case could just be "a" we're looking for. It would also be great if it were generalisable to all character cols rather than having to name them.